# Highchart Does Not Plot when I use Global Variables as Inputs

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

I am creating a function using HighChart as the plotting tool. However when I go to use a global variable in the hcaes() function, nothing gets plotted. Lets use mtcars dataset for the example.

```
x = "mpg"
y = "hp"
hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = "cyl"))

#I am also attempting
hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(x = eval(x), y = eval(y), group = "cyl"))
```

[image]

```
#this works but, I want to use variables rather than the actual string.
hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(x = "mpg", y = "hp", group = "cyl"))
```

[image]

```
#The output I would like to see is 
 x = "mpg"
 y = "hp"
 hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = "cyl"))
```

[image]

Comment: why was this down voted? Can someone produce some code where this works?

Comment: Hi. Your question is asked properly, I don't know why someone downvoted it.
I tried but couldn't make it work. I think that it's more R question, not Highcharts. Maybe you should try to create a thread on R support forum?

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = "mpg"
 y = "hp"
 # x = enexpr(x) you may want to use that, not mandatory
 # y = enexpr(y) you may want to use that  not mandatory

 hchart(mtcars, "point", hcaes(x = !! x, y = !! y, group = "cyl"))
```

This code should work

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer! It might help a bit if you add an explanation as to why this solution works and what makes it tick, that way others can understand exactly _why_ they should do this.